# Question involving Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

The problem is this:
Suppose $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying:

- $ABA = A$ and $BAB =B$
- $A^2 = A$

Is it necessarily true that $B^2=B$?

I have tried playing around a little bit with the relations to see if I can get the result to pop out but that hasn't worked. It is a part of a section on pseudo-inverses but I don't see an obvious way to apply that. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $X$ and $Y$ be any two matrices such that the products $XY$ and $YX$ are well defined. Let
$$
A=\pmatrix{I&0\\ 0&0},\ B=\pmatrix{I&X\\ Y&YX},\ B^2=\pmatrix{I+XY&X+XYX\\ Y+YXY&YX+YXYX}.
$$
Then $A$ is idempotent, $ABA=A$ and $BAB=B$, but $B$ is idempotent if and only if $XY=0$. Surely this is not always the case.